# Android Device Back Menu Opening Issue in Unity Game

Tags: unity-game-engine

I was working on word falling game where we have to type on keyboard different words.

When I was testing a game on Unity editor everything working fine but when I installed the game on actual android device, it was opening back menu panel.

For this, I have recorded a video so you can easily notice the problem - Please watch attached video:
[Back Menu Issue Video Recording Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LhwxCtn8Bb4dk3bDJamuktz5SDIJSD4U/view?usp=share_link)

Because of this game touch events, not able to work properly. I was getting touch down and up event call back issues because of this and my written code can't able to work properly.

Please give me suggestion to sort out this problem for Android device.

Comment: How did you implement the letter-buttons? are they standard unity UI buttons?

Comment: @pixlhero No its just normal Sprite with box collider 2d attached.

Comment: hmm... does it happen on other android devices?

Comment: @pixlhero Still I have not installed within iPhone - May be this is happening because left and right edges of screen working as OS areas so it is opening menu items. Even from the edges swipes will create problem too.

Comment: yes, something like that. maybe you can change some setting on your android? or try a different android phone. Or just on an empty unity scene.

Comment: @pixlhero I can't change android phone settings because after publishing how many people, i will tell to update their phone settings to play the game. Some solution exist for this kind of problem.

Comment: I'm not saying it will be the solution, I'm saying that way you can understand what the problem is.

Comment: @pixlhero Overall in Unity Editor its working perfectly, just in Android device it creating an issue.